# Minimize the Authorize condition in ActionResult

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Because of Sonar, need need to minimise Boolean conditions I have tried it in action results from another action results but it is not redirecting to api error. I have more than 40 authorised conditions and minimise them to 15. please suggest.

```
[HttpPost]
Public ActionResults MethodTest(string request){
if(request.Name==""){
return this.ApiError("Name Required.");
}
------
------
--Like this I have 40 conditions.
----
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the other ifs are all like the one you showed: A simple condition and inside the curly braces just a simple return statement, I would ignore sonar and leave the code like that. The flow is not very complex and easy to follow. You might think of putting this validation logic into a separated method:

```
[HttpPost]
Public ActionResults MethodTest(string request)
{
   if(!Validate(request, out string errorMessage)
   {
      return this.ApiError(errorMessage);
   }

   //normal logic
}

private bool Validate(string request, out string errmorMessage)
{
   if(request.Name=="")
   {
     errorMessage = "Name required";
     return false;
   }

   // other conditions

   errorMessage = null;
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, in this case the Sonar will catch in Validate method.

Comment: As I wrote, I would ignore sonar.